# How can I reduce validation MAE?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I've got a dataset containing 300 columns and target variable.

```
|X_0_0|X_0_1|X_0_2|X_1_0|X_1_1|X_1_2|...|X_99_2|  y  |   
|:---:|:---:|:---:|:---:|:---:|:---:|...|:----:|:---:|
| 3.0 | 48.0| 1.04| 3.0 |78.0 | 1.14|...| 0.01 | 19.0|
| 0.0 | 5.0 |-1.0 | 0.0 | 4.0 |-1.00|...| 1.36 | 25.0|
| 1.0 | 49.0| 3.0 | 3.0 | 90.0| 0.61|...| 0.99 | 22.0|
| 0.0 | 3.0 |-1.0 | 3.0 |28.0 | 2.0 |...| 2.04 | 22.0|
| 3.0 | 0.0 | 1.7 | 0.0 | 5.0 |-1.00|...| 1.16 | 24.0|
```

I've found that X_i_0 takes only following values:

```
sub = train.loc[:,::3] 
for col in sub:
    print(sub[col].unique())
```

Output:

```
[3. 0. 1. 2.]
[3. 0. 1. 2.]
[1. 0. 2. 3.]
[0. 1. 2. 3.]
[1. 0. 2. 3.]
[0. 1. 3. 2.]
[3. 0. 1. 2.]
[0. 3. 1. 2.]
[2. 1. 0. 3.]
[3. 1. 0. 2.]
.............
```

I've executed same code for X_i_1 and X_i_2, they take much more unique values.

I 've also visualized target rate, seemds to have somthing like  [Normal Distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMc4u.png)

I've decided to try sequence model training. I've tried regularisation,dropout, shallow and deep NN, but i couldn't make mae err lesser than 4.5.

```
def create_model(factor, rate): # regularization and Dropout
    model = Sequential([
        Dense(32, kernel_regularizer=l2(factor),activation="relu", input_shape=(n_features,)),
        Dense(16,kernel_regularizer=l2(factor), activation="relu", kernel_initializer='he_normal'),
        Dense(16, kernel_regularizer=l2(factor), activation="relu", kernel_initializer='he_normal'),
        Dense(8, activation="relu", kernel_initializer='he_normal'),
        Dense(1)
    ])
    return model
```

Usual Error results:[Test curve higher than train,overfitting?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8OXY.png)

So I suppose, that I have to preprocess data first, how can I improve data or maybe mae score?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First can you please remove keras from tags this is a basic Machine/Deep Learning  problem .

For the **X_i_0**  it seems to be categories of some objects where each number refer to one specific category .

In other hand the distribution of the Xi data is fuzzy and it can  push the predictions far away from how it should be , so I highly recommend to Normalize/ Standardize your data you can check this [Source](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/04/feature-scaling-machine-learning-normalization-standardization/) and this [One](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/04/feature-scaling-machine-learning-normalization-standardization/)  for a better understanding of data preprocessing

Try to visualize train and validation loss in the same plot to figure out exactly what's going on during the training .

This is an example where it have been applied  Logistic regression

**Case 1 :**

[image]

**Interpretation :**
Typical these are the features of a  **good fit model**

1. Training loss and Validation loss are close to each other with validation loss being slightly greater than the training loss.
2. Initially decreasing training and validation loss and a pretty flat training and validation loss after some point till the end.

**Case 2 :**

[image]

**Interpretation :**

It is a  learning curve of an **overfit model**

1. Training loss and Validation loss are **far away** from each other.
   Gradually decreasing validation loss (without flattening) upon adding training examples.
2. Very low training loss that’s very slightly increasing upon adding training examples.

**Case 3 :**

[image]

[image]

Interpretation :

the learning curve of an **underfit model**

1. **Increasing training loss** upon adding **training examples.**
2. Training loss and validation loss are **close** to each other at **the end**.
3. **Sudden dip** in the training loss and validation loss at the end (not always).

you can check [towards data science](https://towardsdatascience.com/learning-curve-to-identify-overfitting-underfitting-problems-133177f38df5) for more details .

and please add your plots to the question for a better documentation of your problem .

Comment: I removed keras from tags, there was a link to photo of plot in the end, shall i add code?

Comment: @VladislavPanteleev  Okay I see It the problem is overfitting  , yes please add your code , specify what is exactly the problem that you are trying to solve and the features labels if it is not a general application

Comment: Seems that moderator closed question, can I share kaggle notebook here?